# Calculating RMSE of random forest classification in Earth Engine via Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, machine-learning

I tried to transform the [following JS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwje2OiQ0rr-AhVEiv0HHRjGDKsQFnoECCYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffsapps.nwcg.gov%2Fgtac%2FCourseDownloads%2FTraining%2FRemote_Sensing%2FDigitalSoilMapping_EarthEngine_NRCS%2F01_Exercises%2F04.2_DigitalSoilMappinginEarthEngine_RandomForestRegression.docx&usg=AOvVaw2hRMgp13Ox3eeRnqTMTM4v) code to Python to get the RMSE values of my classification.

My ported code is the following

```
sampleTraining = predictedTraining.select(['kat_sajat', 'predicted'])
observationTraining = ee.Array(sampleTraining.aggregate_array('kat_sajat'))
predictionTraining = ee.Array(sampleTraining.aggregate_array('predicted'))

print(observationTraining.subtract(predictionTraining).pow(2).reduce('mean', [0]).sqrt(),'RMSE')
```

The result of this code is an Earth Engine array/json like object instead of a numeric value. I tried to use `getInfo()` function but it timed out. Is it possible to get the RMSE values from these arrays.